# D3js zooming and scaling map with pins

Tags: d3.js, zooming, scale

I made my own map in d3js v4 and put pins (circle) in it. I have implemented zooming but I need to scale circles in visible area.

I tried to google how to do it and I have found this code:

```
const zoom = d3.zoom()
        .on('zoom', () => {
            g.style('stroke-width', `${1.5 / d3.event.transform.k}px`);
            g.attr('transform', d3.event.transform);

            var t = d3.event.transform;
            var xt = t.rescaleX(rScale);
Pins.attr("r", function(d){return xt(d.doc_count);})
        })

    svg.call(zoom);
```

Here is my pins code

```
   var Pins = g.selectAll(".pin")
      .data(data)
      .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("r", function(d){return rScale(d.doc_count);})
    .style("fill", "#caa547") //function(d){ colorScale(d.doc_count)}
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + projection([
          d.agg.location.lon,
          d.agg.location.lat
        ]) + ")";
      })
```

Rscale is define as

```
 var rScale = d3.scaleSqrt().domain([minValue, maxValue]).range([0,10]);
```

And I am geting minValue and maxValue from data set. 
So it would be enough to get just visible area max and min values and change scale. How do I get it?

Comment: Perhaps this will help? http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/9267535

Comment: Thanks but I am using d3.geoMercator and making my own map.